# Automated Design patterns c++

Tags: java, javascript, c++, visual-studio-2010, unix

*Is there a way to automate the creation of Design pattern classes in C++?*
Like an application or a script which takes some inputs and finally throws me a specific design pattern structure with `.cpp` and `.h` classes. I am not sure if I am being ambitious about getting one but something close to this would also do for me. I can modify it according to my requirement.
Any help on this is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to read the "Gang of Four" and have a look at their implementations. Wikipedia will also be your friend (implementations are given), and more generally the Web...

You can also take an UML editor, design a given pattern into and generate the code.